# Shell script executes with double click but not with "run in console"

Tags: java, shell, execution, processbuilder, konsole

So I know that this sounds strange but I don't know why.

I have a shell script which opens a GUI. When i rightclick on the file and click "run in console" this is what I get:

[image: run in console]

Somehow the script just does not keep to continue.

BUT when I try double click on the shell script or running it via console (./vtdStart.sh):

[image: it works]

it works normally.

What can the problem be?

I need to run the script via JAVA:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("//home/bfft/VTD/VTD.2.1/bin/vtdStart.sh");

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(""+line);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    });

    thread.start();

}
```

But as you have already guessed, the programm won't be executed. It is the same "error" as when i try it with "run in console".

Comment: Did you try setting the working directory to `/home/bfft/VTD/VTD.2.1/bin`?

Comment: @BackSlash i tried but it does not work

Comment: What OS are you using ? What is the files explorer ? I can't tell from your screenshots

Comment: @matthiasbe Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @matthiasbe Ubuntu. I just have a different design